# How do I style a single page website for mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Searched around for this a lot already. My html already has:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

And every width in my stylesheet is in %, not px or em.

When I open the page on my phone or a mobile emulator, it has a large horizontal scrollbar and the paragraphs are reduced to one word per line. Any help on this would be appreciated. Sorry, my knowledge of CSS is quite limited as I'm only in my first year of CS.

Comment: This is a really broad question. For starters you should look up media queries. They can be used to apply different CSS styling to elements, when the output device has a certain viewport width and play a big role in responsive webdesign.

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width:400px) { //style }` is your friend